# How to fix ICU Lexing Error: Unexpected character in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-localizations

I am using `flutter_localizations` to localize my app.

Since updating to **Flutter 3.7** i am getting this error:

> ICU Syntax Error: Expected "identifier" but found "}".
>
> This =|(){}[] obviously

`This =|\(){}[] obviously` is the text that i have in my *.arb* file.

I understand that *curly braces* "{}" have a special meaning and should be escaped, but i can not find the way to correctly escape them, has anyone managed to do so?

---

One simple way to reproduce the issue is simply following the steps to add localization support [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-your-own-localized-messages), and then instead of the *hello world* string, write anything that includes the character "`{`".

---

P.S.: There is a [releted issue open on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119375). Be sure to go and check there for updates!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an escaping syntax that is implemented but not enabled by default as it is a new feature that wasn't completely backward compatible with existing ICU message strings.

First, add the following to your `l10n.yaml` file:

```
use-escaping: true
```

Then, this will allow you to wrap parts of your strings in single quotes to ignore any syntax within the single quotes; to use a single quote normally as a character and not an escape, use a double single quote. For example,

```
{
  message: "This '{isn''t}' obvious"
}
```

becomes

```
String get message => "This {isn't} obvious";
```

See [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/messages/#quotingescaping) for information on the syntax. I'll add this to the documentation later.

Comment: I tried enabling this, but I now have hundreds of "unmatched single quotes" errors in my translated arb files. Any automated way of fixing them? :)

Comment: I think finding and replacing all single quotes to a double single quote should do the trick. Your text editor should be able to do this. If not there was a PR I made that relaxes the syntax for the `gen-l10n` parser so that it doesn't treat curly braces as syntax in some scenarios. Check this out: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/130736, but I can't recommend that using this is a good idea.