# Flutter ICU Lexing Error: Unmatched single quotes

Tags: flutter, internationalization, flutter-localizations

I am internationalizing my app, and after adding Serbian and Russian languages, I started getting unexpected character errors as per [How to fix ICU Lexing Error: Unexpected character in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263861/how-to-fix-icu-lexing-error-unexpected-character-in-flutter)

Implementing the fix there
", add the following to your l10n.yaml file:

`use-escaping: true`
"
however started causing hundreds of alerts for single quotes. Eg in my French files that had no issues before. Any tips for a quick fix?